# wxPython List Ctrl: Add Column and Images

Tags: python, wxpython

I am getting an error trying to make a column and add images to "browserlist". The error from the command line says "can't add column in non report mode".

How can I simply add this icons and their corresponding names, i.e. "Google chrome" to the list ctrl?

```
images=['/Desktop/chromelogo.png', 'Desktop/firefoxlogo.png']
browserlist=wx.ListCtrl(panel, pos=(255, 100), size=(220, 100))
browserlist.InsertColumn(0, '')

self.il = wx.ImageList(40,40,True)
for i in images:
    self.il.Add(wx.Bitmap(i))
```

I want it to look kind of like the leftside of the window below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the `ListCtrl` example in the wxPython demo (install it **now** if you do not have it). It has icons prepended to the row text. To be able to add columns you have to set the style to **`wx.LC_REPORT` (EDIT)** <strike>(you will be limited to 16x16 icons in that mode)</strike> **(EDIT3, not true)**.

**EDIT2**: Full example added (modified wxPython demo ListCtrl example)

**EDIT4**: Example modification, remove list unpacking.

[image: with screenshot]

```
import  wx

test_list_data = {
1 : ("New", "Explanation text new"),
2 : ("Open", "Explanation text open"),
3 : ("Copy", "Explanation text copy"),
4 : ("Paste", "Explanation text paste")}

class TestListCtrlPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        BMP_SIZE = 24
        tsize = (BMP_SIZE, BMP_SIZE)
        self.il = wx.ImageList(BMP_SIZE, BMP_SIZE)

        # bitmap generation, uses stock bitmaps included in wxPython
        new_bmp =  wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_NEW, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, tsize)
        open_bmp = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, tsize)
        copy_bmp = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_COPY, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, tsize)
        paste_bmp= wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_PASTE, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, tsize)

        self.bmpdict = {1: new_bmp, 2: open_bmp, 3: copy_bmp, 4: paste_bmp}

        # mapping wxImageList indices to keys in test_list_data
        self.imglistdict = {}

        for idx, bmp in self.bmpdict.iteritems():
            self.imglistdict[idx] = self.il.Add(bmp)

        self.listctl = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1,
                                 style=wx.LC_REPORT 
                                 #| wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                                 | wx.BORDER_NONE
                                 | wx.LC_EDIT_LABELS
                                 | wx.LC_SORT_ASCENDING
                                 #| wx.LC_NO_HEADER
                                 #| wx.LC_VRULES
                                 #| wx.LC_HRULES
                                 #| wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL
                                 )

        self.listctl.SetImageList(self.il, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)
        sizer.Add(self.listctl, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.PopulateList()

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

    def PopulateList(self):
        # header creation
        info = wx.ListItem()
        info.m_mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT
        info.m_image = -1
        info.m_format = 0
        info.m_text = "Artist"
        self.listctl.InsertColumnInfo(0, info)

        info.m_text = "Title"
        self.listctl.InsertColumnInfo(1, info)

        # ListCtrl data generation
        items = test_list_data.items()
        for key, data in items:
            imglist_idx = self.imglistdict[key]
            index = self.listctl.InsertImageStringItem(key, data[0], imglist_idx)
            self.listctl.SetStringItem(index, 1, data[1])
            self.listctl.SetItemData(index, key)

class listctltest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.pnl = TestListCtrlPanel(self, -1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frm = listctltest(None, -1, 'title')
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can also have a look at `UltimateListCtrl` in the demo if this has something you want.

`wx.DataViewListCtrl` (`wxPython` >= 2.9 ) is the most advanced of the builtins and has also the possibility to add icons to a list.

Not included in this list (because I have no experience in it): `ObjectListView`.

Comment: I am only getting a blank box...I have tried playing around with my code. I don't want to use UltimateListCtrl

Comment: Sorry, wrong style constant (edited, see also @Werner s example). Have you tried the ``ListCtrl`` example from the demo?

Comment: Your "answer" just isn't very helpful. Everyone who comments regarding wxpython ListCtrl's makes it seem much easier than it is. This is the only part of wxPython that I cannot get.

Comment: I have never alleged that the ``ListCtrl`` is easy to use. Therefore I have pointed you to the implementation of it in the wxPython demo (which works and you obviously did not have a look at). You have also not reacted to the proposal from @werner . You have also not shown any code modifications from your side. So what do you expect us to do now?

Comment: I did definitely look at the demo. That didn't help me though.  It just showed a visual example of a listctrl. It didn't provide any help with the actual programming .I'll just update the code above with what i have currently.

Comment: See minimal example (EDIT2).

Comment: @ohbrobig: I suppose you noticed that the wxPython demo also has the code samples included to play around with (tab Demo code on the upper right)?

Comment: I did not. Thanks for that. This helps alot.

Comment: Two things I don't understand however. Can you explain this line: "self.il = wx.ImageList(*tsize)". I particularly don't understand *tsize. I know python doesn't have pointers, so I am clueless what *tsize is exactly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pointers and is called argument unpacking, see [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Sorry for making the simple example confusing. EDIT4 writes it in a more comprehensible way.

Comment: Any idea why the demo has the SetItemData call? I have data I was already storing there, before wanting to add the images... is the SetItemData call needed for proper functionality? Also, have you seen any way to get the column headers to be left-justified, as they are when no images are used in the list?

Answer (score 0):

"can't add column in non report mode" gives you the hint.
see: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ListCtrl.html?highlight=listctrl#styles-window-styles

So change:

```
browserlist=wx.ListCtrl(panel, pos=(255, 100), size=(220, 100))
```

to:

```
browserlist=wx.ListCtrl(panel, pos=(255, 100), size=(220, 100), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
```